# Is there a keyboard shortcut to go to a line number in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

I'm using NetBeans for a project, and baffled that I seem completely unable to find a keyboard shortcut to go to a specific line number.

Please tell me that it's my googling skills that are lacking, rather than the IDE.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>

[Keyboard shortcuts for navigating your code in NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/editor-codereference.html#goto)

Answer (score 4):

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd> to go to a specific line.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
works for me in version 7.3

Answer (score 1):

Version 7.1 has an apparent default of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Answer (score -2):

Press Ctrl + G to go to a specific line.

Comment: Exact duplicate of several previous answers.